# Particles flying around

Tags: particles

I am following Blender Guru's tutorial and I'm making particles on my icing. Unfortunately, they are flying around my icing instead of just lay on it. What's wrong?

[image]

Comment: Is the particle physics set to Newtonian?

Comment: It was, and when I change it to ,none' my particles are invisible. They disappear...

Answer (score 1):

When in doubt. go back in the tutorial. Pay attention to the section where the author sets the particles. For static particles use physic type to none.
[image]

Comment: When I set physics type to none, my particles disappear. I am making them as ,hair' and following tutorial in every step and still can not do that.

Comment: Again: When in doubt, go back in the "tutorial", if the "tutorial" does not explain clearly, then find one that does.

Comment: @FilipBlend "Hair" is correct. The emitter particle type will emit the specified object, "throwing" copies of it off the target. A hair will simply place the specified object on the surface of the object. 


On the topic of this answer, please don't answer a question by referring the person back to a tutorial.