# Why do my particles disappear when changing their physics to 'None'?

Tags: particles, physics

I've got a problem with particles: [Particles flying around](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/161603/particles-flying-around)

When I change the physics settings to 'none', particles immediately disappear:

[image]
When the physics are set to 'Newtonian' particles are flying around the icing instead of laying on it.
[image]

What's wrong?

Comment: Did you set particles to Hair? I can't see it.

Comment: Yes, I did :) As you can see below, I fixed my problem in another way!I know its an English website, but... Wesołych Świąt Łukasz! :)

Comment: Dzięki, nawzajem. Good to see more Polish people here. You can give your city in your profile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so I fixed it by myself, just by deleting previous object 'sphere' and creating new one. Here are the settings which work good:
[image]

So I don't know why it wasn't working with previous object, but the solution is to replace it with a new one :)